# How do I know what is in the cell so I can clear all of them at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that I download from another SIS. I am trying to use function `COUNTA`. It is showing that all cells have something in them even though nothing shows in the cell. I can filter and clear contents but that is time-consuming because of the number of columns.  How do I know what is in the cell so I can clear all of them at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Without a better example of what you are doing, this is too vague of a question. Can you give us an example of how your data is laid out and an example of your formula? Also, since `COUNTA` returns the number of cells that are *not empty*, and the range you reference in the formula has formulas, those cells will be counted as being *not empty*.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank

Answer (score 0):

To clear your pseudo-empties, run this short macro:

```
Sub ClearPseudoEmpties()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value = "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(r) <> 0 Then
            r.ClearContents
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```